# Scala Akka RestartSource onFailuresWithBackoff not working complaining dead letters encountered

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I have created a `RetryFlow` like below,following this article https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/RetryFlow/withBackoff.html

```
private val httpFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] =
    Http().outgoingConnection(host, port)

val retryFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] =
RetryFlow.withBackoff(minBackoff = 10.millis, maxBackoff = 5.seconds, randomFactor = 0d, maxRetries = 20, httpFlow)(
  decideRetry = {
    case (request: HttpRequest, response) =>
      response.status match {
        case StatusCodes.OK => Some(request)
        case _ => None
      }
  })
```

And then processing flow like

```
val request = Post(Uri(path), some_json_payload)(
      stringMarshaller(MediaTypes.`application/json`),
      system.executionContext
    )
httpClient.processRequest(request, retryFlow) map (...)
```

My http client looks like below, added a `RestartSettings` and restarting source on `onFailuresWithBackoff`

```
class HttpClient(implicit val system: ActorSystem[_]) {
  implicit val materializer: Materializer = Materializer(system)

  private def checkSuccess(response: HttpResponse, path: String): Either[Throwable, HttpResponse] =
    Either.cond(
      response.status == StatusCodes.OK,
      response,
      new Throwable(s"Could not GET $path, Service returned ${response.status.toString()}"),
    )

  private def httpRequest(
    request: HttpRequest,
    flow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any],
  ): Future[Either[Throwable, HttpResponse]] =
   Source.single(request).via(flow)
    .runWith(Sink.head) map { response =>
    checkSuccess(response, request.uri.path.toString())
  }

  private def unmarshallString(response: Either[Throwable, HttpResponse]): Future[Either[Throwable, String]] =
    response.fold(
      err => Future(err.asLeft[String]),
      r => Unmarshal(r.entity).to[String].map(_.asRight[Throwable]),
    )

  def processRequest(request: HttpRequest, flow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any]): Future[Enclosed[Json]] =
    httpRequest(request, flow) flatMap unmarshallString map (_.flatMap(parse))
}
```

I am pretty new especially in `akka` , what I am missing here .

Comment: This likely isn't the cause of your issue, but there's not really a point in putting just `Source.single(request)` in a `RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff`, since the only thing that _might_ cause a failure is `request` being `null`, which isn't something that will get better if you restart.

Comment: ...so I wonder if you've oversimplified the code to the point where the issue isn't happening.

Comment: Based on your feedback , I have edited my solution. But still I am unable to make this `retry` work.